# How to import and use big CSV files in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, csv

I am building an iphone app that will provide the user with information about public transport departure times. Now I have all of these data stored in huge CSV files (120 000 rows in total, about 60 MB). What is the most convenient way to import these files into my app and then use them for additional coding? Storing in dictionaries, database or using Core Data etc.?

I would prefer to save the data within the app, so it works offline on an iphone.  Thank you.

Comment: cant you prepare a sqlite file beforehand (e.g. server side) and then use sqlite or core data to work with that.... 120.000 records and 60mb is quite a lot ;)

Comment: It is :) .. I already tried working with that using CSV parser to import the data into dictionaries and sorting them but the calculations were really slow :)

 I am new to programming and will have to study a lot to use any of the solutions proposed. I want to make sure I will study the right thing :)

Comment: what you should do and is the correct way is to create a Database. Look into Core Data. importing the data and creating the DB is basically parsing the CSV and import the dictionary. the 'main' iOS app then only needs to interact with CoreData

Comment: Import your csv as proposed into a database in a background thread and show a progress/wait UI while doing it. Don't try it in the main thread. If you block the main thread too long the app will be closed by iOS (it looks like a crash).

Comment: Shipping this data in the app will deny users up-to-date data.  Offline can still work with remote data if the most pertinent subset is cached locally.